# ACF переменные в строке через echo для foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Как правильно сделать из такой строки в обычном формате, сделать для вывода repeater когда заданы подгруппы.
`<li><a href="<?php the_sub_field('col-footer-href'); ?>"><p><?php the_sub_field('col-footer-ul-li-p'); ?></p></li>`
В таком формате

```
$rows = $footer['col-footer']['col-footer-ul-li'];
if( $rows ) {
    echo '<ul class="social">';
    foreach( $rows as $row ) {
        $row10 = wpautop( $row['col-footer-href'] );
        $row20 = wpautop( $row['col-footer-ul-li-p'] );
        echo '<li><a href=" ' . $row10 . '"><p><' . $row20 . '></p></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

у меня только так работает repeater, когда использую вложенные поля.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
$rows = $footer['col-footer']['col-footer-ul-li'];
if( $rows ) {
    echo '<ul class="social">';
    foreach( $rows as $row ) {
        echo '<li>sub_field_1 = ' . $row['col-footer-href'] . ', sub_field_2 = ' . $row['col-footer-ul-li-p'] .', etc</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```